# error al publicar sitio Azure

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2015, azure, mvc

Cree una aplicación con la plantilla de WebAplication de **Visual Studio 2015** con MVC, esta maneja los **Scripts** y **CSS** por bundle, resulta que cuando hago la publicación en **Azure** no me carga ningún estilo, no he podido hacer que se publique de forma correcta.

¿Alguien me podría orientar como realizo la publicación correctamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi suposición es que **el directorio que contiene tus bundles (content/css por ejemplo) existe fisicamente en tu aplicación**. En ese caso **IIS** estaría manejando la request y no el pipeline de MVC.

Asegúrate que el directorio virtual para el bundle(el parametro de SyleBundle o ScriptBundle) no coincida con ningun folder en el sistema de archivos.

> Una buena idea es que al crear nuestros bundles incluyamos un prefijo
>   que no exista como bundle por ejemplo. Esto prevendria posibles
>   problemas de ruteo.